# In Chrome Developer Tools, what does it mean when an object is prefixed with "constructor"?

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using `ExtJs`, and I want to get a snapshot of all of my `Stores` (The state of the app), so I figure I'll walk the root `Stores` and collect each `data` property (provided the value is not itself an `ExtJs` `Store`).

If I check the developer console I can see that the plain old objects I want are not prefixed with `constructor`, but the `Stores` (Classes that `ExtJs` uses to handle state) are prefixed with `constructor`.

[image: constructor prefixes]

I initially thought that being prefixed with `constructor` had something to do with the way the object was instantiated, but I could not reproduce the `constructor` prefix with any of the following.

```
> (function() {return {}})()
< {}

> class test {}
< undefined
> new test()
< test {}

> class test2 extends test{}
< undefined
> new test2()
> test2 {}

> new (function() {})
< {}

> function test3() {}
< undefined
> new test3()
< test3 {}

> Object.fromEntries(Array(20).fill(0).map((_, i) => [`${i}_someproperty`, "yeet"]))
< {0_someproperty: "yeet", 1_someproperty: "yeet", 2_someproperty: "yeet", 3_someproperty: "yeet", 4_someproperty: "yeet", …}

> {}
< {}

> (function(){return {}})()
< {}
```

What does it mean or how can I check if an Object is given the `constructor` prefix by the Chrome Developer Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ExtJS, but this looks to me very likely to be the result of some kind of generic subclass creation using a function that happens to be always named `constructor`, e.g.

```js
function makeExtension(original) {
  // old-style prototype/constructor extension
  function constructor() {
    original.apply(...arguments);
  }
  constructor.prototype = Object.create(original.prototype);
  return constructor;
}

// old-style constructor
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.m = function() { console.log("hello world"); };

let Bar = makeExtension(Foo);
```

Given this, the objects are shown in the console/inspector with "constructor" in their type position:

```
> new Bar()
< ▸ constructor {}
```